# Why only some classes work on my tailwind project(they work with CDN but not when installed localy)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

some classes don't work on my project. Please take a look at the example below, even when I wanted to apply some paddings with `p-4` class, it just dont't work.

Take a look at the problem

[image: 1]

Comment: Share your code

Comment: @MagnusEffect this is the code pen; 
(https://codepen.io/amirreza99/pen/abYaabE)

Thank you.